# Updating Database from form entry in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to update an access database with the data entered into a form. When I hit the insert button, it updates the datagridview in the other form (so I can see the data), but it does not populate the database. What am I missing?

```
    Dim newCoinsRow As CoinsDatabaseDataSet.CoinsRow
    newCoinsRow = frmCollection.CoinsDatabaseDataSet.Coins.NewCoinsRow
    newCoinsRow.Name = strName
    newCoinsRow.Year = intYear
    newCoinsRow.FaceValue = decFaceValue
    newCoinsRow.Currency = strCurrency
    newCoinsRow.Metal = strMetal
    newCoinsRow.Weight = decWeight
    newCoinsRow.Value = decValue
    newCoinsRow.IsEncapsulated = boolEncapsulated
    frmCollection.CoinsDatabaseDataSet.Coins.Rows.Add(newCoinsRow)
    frmCollection.CoinsTableAdapter.Update(frmCollection.CoinsDatabaseDataSet.Coins)
```

In the form with the datagrid view, I have this:

```
    Private Sub frmCollection_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.CoinsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CoinsDatabaseDataSet.Coins)

End Sub
```

Comment: Been a looooong time since I've used typed datasets, and even back then not that often, so just a comment... but try calling `CoinsDatabaseDataSet.Update()`

Comment: Just as you call `Fill` on a table adapter to populate a `DataTable` in a `DataSet`, so you need to call `Update` on that same table adapter to save the changes from that `DataTable` back to the database.

Comment: OK, I didn't notice that you actually are calling `Update` because that line wasn't formatted with the rest of the code.  I'll have a closer look when I get a chance.

Comment: By the way, you're dropping out of the typed `DataSet` with this line: `frmCollection.CoinsDatabaseDataSet.Coins.Rows.Add(newCoinsRow)`. Your typed `DataTable` has its own method for adding a new row. It believe that that line should be something like this: `frmCollection.CoinsDatabaseDataSet.Coins.AddCoinsRow(newCoinsRow)`.

Comment: @Kevin, your code to add and update the row is valid. Something else is going on.  Could you explain a little more about exactly what you are seeing and how you are debugging this?

Comment: The data that I enter into the first form is populating in the datagrid of the second form. However, that data is not being saved to the database. When I preview the data in the database and/or open it in Access, it is only showing the values that were manually added to the database, not the values that are showing up in the form.